# How to reliably emulate the HTML5 'input' event, using the DOM 'keyup' event *ON A TOUCH DEVICE*

Tags: dom, dom-events

Older browsers (particularly mobile browsers) don't yet support the HTML5 'input' event, which fires every time the value of a text field (for example) actually changes.

So, one would like to reconstruct this by trapping the `keyup` event, and keeping track of all the <kbd>LEFT</kbd>, <kbd>RIGHT</kbd>, <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> and <kbd>DEL</kbd> keys, as well as the printable characters which are entered.  That's plenty of hassle right there.

However, on a *touch* device, the user can position the cursor into the middle of the existing text and type a character smack bang in the middle of it.  We can only predict what the value of the field will be after `keyup` if we know the position of the cursor when we receive the event.

And we can't get that current-position-of-cursor-within-the-input-element info from anywhere.  Therefore, we can't reliably emulate the 'input' event.

Am I sadly right, or have I overlooked something?